# PySpark Overwrite Approach issue Same table

Tags: pyspark, hive

I am trying to overwrite the table which part of source as well. As we are aware it can't be done both the scenarios on same table.

So i created Spark temp table and and tried overwriting the hive table but i still got the same error.
then i tried crating physical hive table(temp purposes and overwritten everytime) then overwritten the actual table. it works fine. But I am getting the error when i trying 2nd time Error is as below:

```
df.registerTempTable("temp_actual")
spark.sql("insert overwrite table schema.temp_actual select * from temp_actual")
spark.sql(insert overwrite table schema.actual select * from schema.temp_actual")

Error:
Cannot create the managed table(schema.temp_actual) associated location <path> is already exists schema.temp.actual.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this property:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.allowCreatingManagedTableUsingNonemptyLocation","true")
```

or much better remove the directory because in spark 3.0 this property will not work